# t-structures on the tensor product of stable $\infty$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, stable-homotopy, monoidal-categories

It is a matter of checking definitions that the [tensor product of presentable $\infty$-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+presentable+%28infinity%2C1%29-categories) restrict to a tensor product between stable presentable $\infty$-categories; I was wondering if there is a natural way to classify, or to build, $t$-structures on the tensor product ${\cal C}\otimes{\cal D}$ in terms of $t$-structures on $\cal C$ and $\cal D$.

This problem has a 1-dimensional counterpart (not really 1-1 correspondence of statements and proofs, but..): is there a way to construct a torsion theory on the [Deligne tensor product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Deligne+tensor+product+of+abelian+categories) of abelian categories (provided it exists), given torsion theories on the factors?

Comment: Looks like DAG VIII.4.6 does this: there's a tensor product on the category of pairs of presentable stable infty cats and accessible t structures. The definition is a bit hard to unwind but VIII.4.6.8 gives an explicit description of the nonpositive part of the t-structure in good cases.

Comment: Appendix A in SAG also gives a (maybe more user-friendly) definition of tensor product of accessible t-structures, specifically Remark A.3.4.12.