# t-structures on the tensor product of stable $\infty$-categories, II

Tags: ct.category-theory, stable-homotopy, triangulated-categories

I fork from [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231763/t-structures-on-the-tensor-product-of-stable-infty-categories) thread, a bunch of questions stemmed from a private conversation about that thread. Speculating a bit on the definition of the tensor operation between t-structures generated some interesting thoughts:

1. A nice definition of a t-structure on the tensor product ${\cal C}\otimes{\cal D}$ must entail that the canonical t-structure $\bf s$ generated by connective spectra on $\text{Sp}$ behaves like a unit, in the sense that
   $$
   \mathbf{t}\otimes \bf s = t
   $$
   for each $\bf t$ a t-structure on $\cal C$. It is an instant corollary of this that ${\bf t}\otimes ({\bf s}[n]) = {\bf t}[n]$, so "tensoring with the canonical t-structure or its shifts behaves itself like a shift".

   Now, in principle there can be *another* t-structure $\bf a$ on $\text{Sp}$, such that ${\bf a}\otimes {\bf t} = {\bf t}'$, i.e. $\bf t$ on $\cal C$ is sent to another $\bf t'$ on $\cal C$ by the isomorphism $\text{Sp}\otimes\cal C \cong C$; this gives rise to a (apparently nontrivial) endomorphism of the (po)set of t-structures on $\cal C$, let's call it $\tau_{\bf a}$ like ''twisting''.

   > Q1: Are there other t-structures on $\text{Sp}$ apart from the
   >   canonical one and its shifts?

Suppose now we have a solid, handy definition of the tensor product of t-structures.

2. The set of t-structures $\text{ts}({\cal C})$ becomes a fairly rich gadget; it's a poset, a monoid (under the tensor operation $\otimes$), and a $\mathbb{Z}$-set (shift by 1 a t-structure);

   > Q2: Do all these data interact nicely?

   I've never heard of a general theory of partially ordered monoids with a monotone, multiplicative action of the group of integers...
3. One can speculate (notations as point 1) on the invertibility of the map $\tau_{\bf a}\colon \text{ts}({\cal C})\to \text{ts}({\cal C})$, i.e. about the cancellativity of the monoid $\text{ts}({\cal C})$ and the possibility to describe every $\bf t'$ as a suitable ${\bf a}\otimes {\bf t}$; one can also speculate about invertible elements in this monoid, i.e. about when ${\bf t}\otimes{\bf t}'=\bf s$. And so on, and so on...

   > Q3: has something similar been studied by anybody out there?

Comment: As for Q1: there are *lots* of t-structures on Sp. For example: For any spectrum E the category of E-acyclics forms the nonnegative part of a t-structure on Sp.

Comment: (It's worth noting that the heart of the corresponding t-structure is trivial, and that this t-structure has the weird property that the bounded above and bounded below objects are both closed under suspensions and desuspensions)

Comment: Ah, yes, Bousfield localization! Thanks. I dont think they're that weird :) it depends on your taste. A more interesting remark is that tensoring with a stable t-structure $s$ blatantly fails to be injective, since $(t[1])\otimes s = t\otimes (s[1]) = t\otimes s$. Now any non stable t-structure must form an ascending/descending chain of its suspensions/desuspensions, so...